# Advice on the layout of a rendering system architecture -Real time/HLSL/DirectX9/C++

Tags: c++, architecture, real-time, hlsl, directx-9

I want to create a simple but beneficial rendering engine to display the use of shaders etc. I have done research and am still having problems finding any solid examples. Does anyone have a resource that I can look at or can provide some advice on how to get started and what is essential to have.

Comment: **Why are you shouting? This is not a newspaper classifieds section. You will not get more attention with bold text.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with simple stuff at the beginning, to render a mesh in DX11 for example you need at least :

1)A class capable to send commands to the GPU, usually is called renderer capable
to submit all the data required to command the GPU, this class is also responsible to init the rendering engine and to allocate the buffers required to display something on screen

2)A representation of your mesh, so you need a class containing a vertex buffer, an index buffer and a material, the material contains shaders and textures to render your mesh.

The mesh can have a render() method capable to use the renderer to submit rendering commands to the GPU.

If you need more details just let me know